# How to add a role when i join a specific voice discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I did a code for that but I want to more voice-text channels to  the voice channels

```py
@bot.event
async def voice1_role(member, before, after):
    if not before.channel and after.channel:
        role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name="voice1")
        await member.add_roles(role)
    elif before.channel and not after.channel:
        role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name="voice1")
        await member.remove_roles(role)
```

This code adds the same role if I join either of the voice channels, How would I make it give `voice1` role if it joins `Voice1` and `voice2` role if it joins `Voice2`.

Comment: You can use [`channel.name`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.VoiceChannel.name) to access the channel name and determine which role to give/remove based on that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code partly works. However we have to use a different `event` and reform the check in order to use the code for more events/roles.

You can use an [on_voice_state_update](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.VoiceClient.on_voice_state_update) function in order to check in which channel the member is.

```py
@bot.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    channel = before.channel or after.channel

    if channel.id == ChannelID:
        if before.channel is None and after.channel is not None: # Member joins the defined channel
            role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, id=RoleID)
            await member.add_roles(role) # Role is given
        elif before.channel is not None and after.channel is None:
            role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, id=RoleID)
            await member.remove_roles(role) # Role removed because he left the channel
```

*(Note that you can copy the code and insert new channel IDs or role IDs if you want to have more events.)*

***To explain the different functions in the code:***

`before.channel is None` = Checks that the user is not in a channel/was not in a channel.

`after.channel is not None` = Checks the channel which the user joined and then grants the role.

`before.channel is notn None and after.channel is None` = User is not in a channel anymore.

***What we did was the following:***

- Changed the check: We check the channel before and after the member joined a channel. This will either restult in `add_roles` or `remove_roles`
- `name` was changed to `id` so that you can rename the role and do not have to change your code.
- Used `channel.id` instead of name so you can once again change it whenever you want to